# For what values of $a > 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is the following function integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

For what values of $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ is the

$$ f:(1,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}: f(x) = \frac{\arctan(x^\alpha)}{x^\beta}$$

function integrable ?

I know that the above, an example from my text,  is integrable if and only if $ 1 < \beta < \alpha + 1$. But the text uses Landau notation to estimate the bounds and left me confused as to what is being done.

It states and I quote,

> Note that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x} = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\arctan(x) = \pi/2$. Hence, $f(x) = \Theta(x^{\alpha - \beta})$ for $x \to 0$ and $f(x) = \Theta(\frac{1}{x^\beta})$ for $x\to+\infty$. Hence, $f$ is integrable if and only if $ \beta - \alpha < 1$ and $ \beta > 1$.

I know the above 2 limits exists and have the respective values. But, I have been unable to work out what happened to the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $f$ ? Also, how does this show $f(x) = \Theta(x^{\alpha - \beta})$ ?

A bit of handholding will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:
$$
\alpha>0\implies \lim_{x\to+\infty}x^\alpha=+\infty\implies
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\arctan{x^\alpha}=\frac\pi2,
$$
$$\alpha<0\implies \lim_{x\to+\infty}x^\alpha=0\implies\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\arctan{x^\alpha}}{x^\alpha}=1.$$